# Powershell Regex match and not match in a Foreach If-then not working

Tags: regex, powershell, if-statement

Hows that for a title?

I have this script Ive been working on that does two basic things: a) Use [get-ntfsaccess](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/fieldcoding/2014/12/05/ntfssecurity-tutorial-1-getting-adding-and-removing-permissions/) to pull the security for a folder and then b) use the output to look up the group members of the groups that have access.

```
$Outfile2 = "C:\Users\local\Documents\GroupMembers.csv"
$Header2 = "GroupName,Member"

Add-Content -Value $Header2 -Path $Outfile2

$RootPath = "p:\city\Department\building"
$Folders = get-childitem2 -directory -recurse -path $RootPath 

foreach ($Folder in $Folders){
   $ACLs = Get-NTFSAccess $Folder.fullname  

   Foreach ($ACL in $ACLs){
   If ($Acl.accounttype -match 'group' -and $acl.Account.accountname -notmatch '^builtin|^NT AUTHORITY\\|^Creator|^AD\\Domain')
   {
   $members = Get-ADGroupMember $acl.Account.accountname.TrimStart("AD\\")
   }
   Foreach ($member in $members) {

   $OutInfo = $ACL.Account.AccountName + "," + $member.samaccountname
   Add-Content -Value $OutInfo -Path $OutFile2
   }
   }}
```

Id like to be able to filter the output of get-ntfsaccess. I want to only lookup 'groups' and groups that arent the base groups (like builtin, domain admins, etc) but my match and not match arent working in the script. If I take that exact same line and run it from the prompt - it works.

[image: NotMatch is true]

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $acl.Account.accountname -notmatch '^builtin|^NT AUTHORITY\\|^Creator|^AD\\Domain'
True
```

When run as part of the script - doesnt work. My output includes all of the domain base groups and users. Id like to also eventually add -unique to only get unique groups but this part has got me stumped....

Thanks in advance...!

Comment: `AD\DOMAIN` is not a valid domain shortname

Comment: Thats the ad domain name ("AD") so that is supposed to match for something like "AD\Domain Admins". Even still, shouldn't it match the others or do they all have to be true? Ive tried editing them all out but one out and it still wont match...

Answer (score 0):

I did this with success:

```
((dir)[0] | get-acl).access | % { $_.IdentityReference } | ? { $_ -notmatch 'builtin|nt authority' }
```

I cannot test with ntfsaccess at the moment but get-acl's returned IdentityReference is most likely the same field you are attempting to parse on. You might just try removing your '^'s. I also tested with `"myDomain\\Domain Admins"` and that worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out.

Three main things - 
1. The Trimstart wasn't accepting the '/' no matter how i tried to 'escape' it
2. Had to use get-adgroup to pipe to get-adgroupmember
3. the IF then was script blocked wrong to write each result out at each iteration through $ACLs

```
$Outfile2 = "C:\Users\local\Documents\GroupMembers.csvv"
$Header2 = "GroupName,Member"

Add-Content -Value $Header2 -Path $Outfile2

$RootPath = "p:\city\Department\building"

$Folders = get-childitem2 -directory -recurse -path $RootPath

foreach ($Folder in $Folders){
$ACLs = Get-NTFSAccess $Folder.fullname 

    Foreach ($ACL in $ACLs){
    If ($Acl.accounttype -match 'group' -and $acl.Account.accountname -notmatch '^builtin|^NT AUTHORITY\\|^Creator|^AD\\Domain')
    {$members = Get-adgroup $acl.Account.accountname.substring(3) | Get-ADGroupMember 

    Foreach ($member in $members) {
    $OutInfo = $ACL.account.AccountName + "," + $member.samaccountname
    Add-Content -Value $OutInfo -Path $OutFile2
}}}}
```